# Discover the real color behind EnvironmentColors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm developing a visual studio isolated shell application and I need to know the colors associated to every property of the class EnvironmentColors.
Unfortunately every property seems to be a key to a sort of dictionary or something similar.
Any idea to get the color associated?

Thanks!

Comment: Only a comment but I am not sure they are hard colors.  In Vista and Windows 8 they are not always the same.  If you have a theme installed the colors may change.

Comment: @LarsTech: No, I meant the theme colors of Visual Studio instance

Answer (score 4):

[I wrote a blog post](https://keyoti.com/blog/visual-of-the-actual-colours-in-visual-studios-environmentcolors/) based on this question because I didn't see how the top voted answer addressed it.  There was still the question of; what colour is property XYZ in theme A?

The blog has a (massive, but manageable) image of all the colours, for 3 themes.  [image: Snippet of the swatch] I would love to upload it here but the file is 3.6MB and there's a 2MB limit, also it is about 40K pixels in height, so that might not be welcome inline!

Answer (score 3):

EnvironmentColors are for direct binding to your WPF controls. To get the current value of a theme color in VS 2012+ you can use [IVsUIShell5.GetThemedColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuishell5.getthemedcolor.aspx) (should be re-read on theme changes).

Comment: Great! This is what I need but: how to use IVsUIShell5? I thought was a class, but it is an interface. Who is implementing this interface?

Comment: GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell)) as IVsUIShell5

Comment: I can't find any usage of that method anywhere - what values can the parameters take?

Comment: @mackenir See http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012030.aspx for a GetThemedColor usage sample: GetThemedColor(new System.Guid("624ed9c3-bdfd-41fa-96c3-7c824ea32e3d"), "ToolWindowBackground", 0)

Comment: Thanks - I may be missing something but that only shows one color category and one color property name with no explanation of where those values came from or what the range of possible values are.

Comment: @mackenir You can export a .vstheme file using "Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor" http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe and this xml file contains all possible Category and Name values.

Answer (score -3):

```
foreach (var ColorProperty in typeof(System.Drawing.SystemColors).GetProperties())
{
    var Color = (System.Drawing.Color) ColorProperty.GetValue(null, null);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, R={1}, G={2}, B={3}", ColorProperty.Name, Color.R, Color.G, Color.B);
}
```

Comment: SystemColors is not the same as EnvironmentColors

Comment: I quote @Blam, SystemColors are the colors of windows, not the colors belonging to VS theme